# Postgresql COPY command - how to delete temp file?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have procedure and it works well.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_dynamic_copy(_tbl     text = 'tmp1')
RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _filename VARCHAR;
BEGIN
  _filename := '/tmp/' || random() || '.csv';
  EXECUTE format($$COPY (select id, 1, 1, 1 from my_first_table) TO %L$$, _filename);
  EXECUTE format($$COPY my_second_table FROM %L$$, _filename);
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But I want to delete temporary files created in this procedure. How to do it?

Comment: You can't access the filesystem via neither plpgsql nor SQL for anything other than COPY FROM and COPY TO. You can use a `plperlu` function, or cron jobs to clean up old files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution for [PostgreSQL 9.3+](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-copy.html):

```
-- Delete temporary file
EXECUTE format(
  $$COPY (SELECT 1) TO PROGRAM 'rm %I'$$,
  _filename
);
```

So, my function is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_dynamic_copy(_tbl     text = 'tmp1')
RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _filename VARCHAR;
BEGIN
  _filename := '/tmp/' || random() || '.csv';
  EXECUTE format($$COPY (select id, 1, 1, 1 from my_first_table) TO %L$$, _filename);
  EXECUTE format($$COPY my_second_table FROM %L$$, _filename);

  -- Delete temporary file
  EXECUTE format(
    $$COPY (SELECT 1) TO PROGRAM 'rm %I'$$,
    _filename
  );

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Yes, it is trick, hack. In my case filename has absolutely controlled structure, therefore Im sure this is secure solution. If attacker will override `random()` or `format()` function, I may have problem. But such fact - is very bad. And this should not happen.

Answer (score 1):

plpgsql does not have a function to delete files. You would need to create the stored function in perl or [python](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/plpython.html) to be able to delete the temporary file. But do you really need a temporary file here wouldn't an INSERT SELECT do the job just as well with the need for a stored function?

```
INSERT INTO my_second_table SELECT id, 1, 1, 1 from my_first_table
```

Comment: Is there are significant difference here in performance? Well if COPY is t he only option, I guess it will have to be plpython or similar

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/populate.html
"Note that loading a large number of rows using COPY is almost always faster than using INSERT, even if PREPARE is used and multiple insertions are batched into a single transaction".
In my case COPY faster than INSERT in 5 times.